# Moved WordPress install within server - now plugins not working

Tags: wordpress

I moved my Wordpress blog to a new directory and new user on the same server, but now it seems that jquery/javascript effects are not working.

Specifically, I have a javascript redirect to a confirmation page on submission of a "Contact Form 7" plugin's form. The form submits (evidenced by my receipt of the emails), but I am not redirected to the confirmation page. The little indicator just keeps on spinning indefinitely.

For example: see http://www.zestylogos.com/contact/

Any suggestions for how to fix this? I can provide any additional information as necessary.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's definitely a problem with your path translations;

```
<!-- WP Super Cache is installed but broken. The path to wp-cache-phase1.php in wp-content/advanced-cache.php must be fixed! -->
```

By any chance, is your set-up something like this?

```
Document Root: /user/public_html
WordPress Install: /user/public_html/wordpress
```

Are you overriding any default directory constants like `WP_CONTENT_DIR` in `wp-config.php`?

Try de-activating all your plugins, then activate and check one-by-one to see if any could be causing problems.

Also run through your WP Super Cache settings and see if it's reporting any problems. Double check and re-save your settings (I believe WP Super Cache, depending on the aggression level, stores absolute paths in your `.htaccess`).

Don't forget to clear your existing cache too.

Comment: I was not overriding any default constants, but my WP Super Cache configuration was screwy. Problem fixed. Thanks for the help!